# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory | npm-created files

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

When I run a simple npm script to start a test, I get a peculiar error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\e2e-1656352094051.cmd'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
    at writeFileSync (node:fs:2170:35)
    at makeSpawnArgs (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\lib\make-spawn-args.js:82:3)
    at runScriptPkg (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\lib\run-script-pkg.js:57:55)
    at runScript (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script\lib\run-script.js:9:16)
    at RunScript.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\run-script.js:125:13)
    at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:5)
```

`e2e` is the name of the script I'm trying to run, which makes me think that `e2e-1656352094051.cmd` is the name of a file that `npm` created for itself. But how am I supposed to make sure that such a file exists when `npm` is the process responsible for creating the file?

I've tried searching for answer to the problem, but it's a little difficult when `no such file or directory` is an error message that's present for thousands of issues that are completely unrelated to my own problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had updated my version of npm that morning, and that this update (8.13) causes some quirks with the Windows filesystem when combined with script names that include a colon. I've filed a [ticket](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5093) with the GitHub page for the npm cli, and changed the names of my scripts to use hyphens instead of colons for now.